# How to connect localhost database with php?

Tags: php, sql

I have created database in localhost and connected to php. but it shows error

i have tried but could not found

db.php:

```
<?php 

$con=mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'login_db');

 ?>
```

init.php:

```
<?php 
include("db.php");
include("functions.php");

if ($con) {

    echo "CONNECTED";
}

 else echo "NO";

 ?>
```

It returns "NO". It should be connected

Comment: What's the error?  That will probably help uncover the issue

Comment: `$con=mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'login_db');` This should works. You can also try to replace `localhost` with `127.0.0.1`